# Chrome screen sharing get monitor info

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I implemented chrome extension which using `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` to retrieve screen id.
This is my background script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler);

    // listen to "content-script.js"
    function messageHandler(message) {
        if(message == 'get-screen-id') {
            chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'window'], port.sender.tab, onUserAction);
        }
    }

    function onUserAction(sourceId) {

        //Access denied
        if(!sourceId || !sourceId.length) {
            return port.postMessage('permission-denie');
        }

        port.postMessage({
            sourceId: sourceId
        });
    }
});
```

I need to get shared monitor info(resolution, landscape or portrait).

My question is: If customer using more than one monitor, how can i determine which monitor he picked? 
Can i add for example "system.display" permissions to my extension and get picked monitor info from `"chrome.system.display.getInfo"`?

Comment: Did you figure this out by any chance? I tried the `...display.getInfo` API, and that returns an array of the available displays, but I have no way to identify which one the user selected, since in the `chooseDesktopMedia` callback I only get the `sourceId` which is a stream id to send to `getUserMedia` webrtc API... I am starting to think that this might not be possible at all.

Comment: it was not possible at the time when I was working on it (about a year ago) and i did not found solution to this problem. I'm not working on this project at the moment, maybe a new version of chrome already has a solution. The only way to know is check it again. Also read about changes in  canary version. Good luck )

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I am checking it these days. I can tell you that it's not possible just with the `sourceId` and the `getInfo` API at the moment, but I am checking some webRTC APIs that could give me the info, since in Chrome, in webrtc-internals I can see the screen selected in the `addStream` method. Will post any updates or even an answer if I figure it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You could add system.display permission and call [chrome.system.display.getDisplayLayout](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display#method-getDisplayLayout)(callbackFuncion([DisplayLayout](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display#type-DisplayLayout))) and handle the DisplayLayout.position in the callback to get the layout and the [chrome.system.display.getInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display#method-getInfo) to handle the array of displayInfo in the callback. You should look for 'isPrimary' value

Answer (score 1):

This is a year old question, but I came across it since I was after the same information and I finally managed to figure how you can identify which monitor the user selected for screen-sharing in Chrome.

First of all: this information **will not come from the extension that you probably built for screen-sharing in Chrome**, because:

- The `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` API callback only returns a `sourceId`, which is a string that represents a stream id, that you can then use to call the `getMediaSource` API to build the media stream.
- The `chrome.system.display.getInfo` will give you a list of the displays, yes, but from that info you can't tell which one is being shared, and there is no way to match the `sourceId` with any of the fields returned for each display.

So... **the solution I've found comes from the `MediaStream` object itself**. Once you have the stream, after calling `getMediaSource`, you need to get the video track, and in there you will find a property called "label". This label gives you an idea of which screen the user picked.

You can get the video track with something like:

```
const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
```

(Check the `getVideoTracks` API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/getVideoTracks).

If you print that object, you will see the "label" field. In Chrome screen 1 shows as "0:0", whereas screen 2 shows as "1:0", and I assume screen i would be "i-1:0" (I've only tested with 2 screens).
Here is a capture of that object printed in the console:

[image: video track (Chrome)]

---

And not only works for Chrome, but for other browsers that implement it! In Firefox they show up as "Screen i":

[image: video track (Firefox)]

---

Also, if you check Chrome `chrome://webrtc-internals` you'll see this is what they show in the `addStream` event:

[image: Chrome webrtc-internals addStream event]

---

And that's it! It's not ideal, since this is a label, more than a real screen identifier, but well, it's something to work with. Once you have the screen identified, in Chrome you can work with the `chrome.system.display.getInfo` to get information for that display.

Comment: Hi, I followed your example on Chrome 70 but now the label shows "screen:69733442" for the default screen (builtin)